# Install Adobe flash player 10.1 on Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator, flash, android-2.2-froyo

How can installed Adobe flash player 10.1 on Android simulator 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

Hi sujay1407 until now thats not possible, I asked directly to a google engineer, necessarily needed an android device with hardware and software required for Flash Player 10.1

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/articles/content_mobilization_faq.html#q07

Answer (score 0):

Here you can download APKs for various versions of Android. They also install properly on the emulator, however I don't know if they actually are able to run.

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

edit: nope, it installs but does not seem to work. I've just tested http://www.adobe.com/swf/software/flash/about/flashAbout_info_small.swf on emulator and empty black page showed up.